# What declarations should be placed in a C header file?

Tags: c, header-files

There exists a header file for almost each .c file in my project. All typedefs and function declarations are placed in header files. But is this a good practice? Some of the typedefs are used only in one of the .c files. Also some of the functions are not called by functions in other source files.

Comment: If they're not used anywhere else (i.e. they're "private") then there is no reason to declare them in a header file.

Comment: And functions and "global" variables that truly are only applicable within the .c module could be declared static.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` is a pre-processing step, so you can stick whatever in there. This is largely a question of style, but it is good programming practice to minimise the impact on the namespace. (Usually) using header files allows a primitive distinction between *public* and *private*, with the *public definitions* being put in the header. That way, a separate compilation unit can include the header and have the definitions resolved when one links them. Anything that is *private* to the compilation unit should not be included unless a *public* declaration has it as it's dependency. Some things that are useful (or essential) to put in header files,

- `typedef`'s that are used in *public* functions, (eg, a pointer-to-function used as an argument to a non-`static` function that is also part of the header);
- `enum` values that are used in *public* functions or are part of the `.h` file's purpose;
- `struct` or `union` declarations, especially if they are in public functions. One does not need to define them if all functions use pointer values, (data hiding is good design, see [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration));
- `#define` in header files should be used sparingly to avoid namespace conflicts, but sometimes it's part of the header's purpose;
- any *private* symbols should be `static`, thus eligible for extra optimisation; anything `static` should not be there, and `main` does not need a prototype, (see [Declare main prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020362/declare-main-prototype));
- `extern` see [C: What is the use of 'extern' in header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727881/c-what-is-the-use-of-extern-in-header-files).

The `c` file should generally `#include` it's `h` file. There are some other uses of header files, too; for example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro.