# Where are variables stored when you have "global" variables in multiple C files?

Tags: c, variables, scope, compiler-construction

When you have multiple C files, say main.c and process.c I was trying to understand where variables declared outside of functions in both cases are stored.

```
// this is main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "process.h"
int foo = 1;

void main() {
   int count = get_counter();
}

// this is process.c
#include <stdio.h>

int counter = 0;

int get_counter() {
    return counter;
{
```

So when you have two c files, your *main.c* and a *process.c*, you can call *get_counter()* in *main.c* and it will return the value from the *process.c* file. What I was trying to understand is where the compiler, or how it stores *int foo* in *main.c* and *int count* in *process.c*? Is this part of some data storage section? It is not on the stack right? It also seems having a separate *process.c* file makes it so it is not a global variable.

I have been really trying to understand how variables scope is handled and can get a little tricky for me. Does the #include *"process.h"* essentially compile as if you had the functions and their prototypes in the *main.c* above the rest of the code? To me that would make the *int counter* global so I know I am confusing something.

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: It's stored in each object file's DATA section.

Comment: When the linker combines the object files, it's concatenates all their data sections, and fixes up the variable references to find them in the appropriate part of that.

Comment: Why do you think it's not a global variable? Each source file has its own set of global variables.

Comment: I might be using my terminology incorrect. The process.c was not global in respect to main.c. I needed a get_counter() in process.c to retrieve that parameter. Was not sure how the code separates data sections where each c code has their own global variables?

Comment: Since `counter` in `process.c` is global, in `main.c` you could have cheated, and said `extern int counter;`, and then said `int count = counter;` directly, without using the accessor function.  To make that `counter` variable private to `process.c`, and disallow `main.c` from cheating in this way, you could change its declaration to `static int counter;`.

Comment: So static would allow the compiler to not allow anyone to access that variable except for the functions in *process.c*? That is a compile time catch? Either way I could not have said, in *main.c*, *count = counter* correct?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055165/advantage-of-using-extern-in-a-header-file/66056029#66056029

Answer (score 1):

That's a function of the executable file format, not the C language itself.  For [ELF](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf) (*nix and similar systems) and [PE/COFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#section-data) (Windows and similar), globals or other objects with `static` storage duration will be stored in either the `.bss` or `.data` sections depending on whether they're initialized or not.  This is space allocated from within the program's binary image itself (not taken from the stack or heap).

Other executable file formats may use different section names.