# global definition of structure instance(object)

Tags: c, struct

I have a question regarding global definition of structure instance/object in header .h file and using that instance in multiple source files.

- I have 3 source files (.c) and their their files (.h).
- In one of header file a structure and its object is defined like below:

```
typedef struct {
    char *my;
    int x;
} main_t;
  
main_t main;
```

Now can I include that header file in other source file and access the member of the same instance **main** of  structure, as it is global

- I have tried and its working but why i am not getting multiple definition error?
- i am not using **extern**

I have asked a problem regarding declaring and using  global object of structure in c.

Comment: 1. Please don't tag C questions with C++. 2. In C you can't do it without `extern`.

Comment: The variable `main` is _not_ a shared global. Every translation unit that includes this header will get its own unique instance of `main_t` called `main`. You will get a link error if somewhere you attempt `extern main_t main;` because the linker won't know which one to use. The solution is to declare the variable `extern` in the header, and then define it in _one_ translation unit.

Comment: Side-note: do you _really_ want to have a variable called `main`? That may cause you problems in code that requires a standard main function.

Comment: "I have tried and its working..." well, why don't you post that code so that we can see exactly what you are doing

Comment: Don't define variables in header files. `main` is a terrible variable name... when programming, don't do really strange things just for the heck of it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question regarding global definition of structure instance/object in header .h file and using that instance in multiple source files.

`main_t main;` at file scope is not a definition. It is a *tentative definition*. (In spite of its name, a tentative definition is not actually a definition, in the same way that a prospective employee on a job interview is not actually an employee.) However, if a translation unit contains a tentative definition and no regular definition, the behavior is as if the translation unit had a definition for the identifier with initializer equal to 0 (C 2018 6.9.2 2).

Then the effect is that all three of your source files contain a definition for `main`. C 2018 6.9 5 says “there shall be no more than one” definition of an external definition. Violating this constraint means the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Since the behavior is not defined by the C standard, C implementations are free to define the behavior (or not). Until GCC version 10, the default behavior in GCC was to treat tentative definitions differently from regular definitions. Multiple tentative definitions are allowed, and they are coalesced to form one definition. Some tools other than GCC might still use this behavior.

Thus, what you are observing is that, with the tools you are using, multiple tentative definitions in different source files act as a single common definition.

With GCC, you can select the old behavior (coalesce tentative definitions) with `-fcommon` or the new behavior (treat tentative definitions as regular definitions) with `-fno-common`.

Additional information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055165/advantage-of-using-extern-in-a-header-file/66056029#66056029).

### Supplement

This is not a *global* definition because C does not have a global name space. In a global name space, declaring an identifier anywhere in the program would make it known throughout the program. In C, the largest scope is file scope, where declaring an identifier makes it known through the rest of the translation unit. To make an identifier known elsewhere in a program, it must be declared in each translation unit where it is used, and these declarations must be linked together. This is file scope with external linkage, not global scope.