# ld: multiple definitions of const variable

Tags: c, makefile, ld, pintos

I am going through the PintOS project using [the JHU version of PintOS](https://github.com/jhu-cs318/pintos). But when I `make` under `src/userprog`(which is `~/Documents/PintOS/userprog/` on my local machine), it throws this error to me:

```
cd build && make all 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pairman/Documents/PintOS/userprog/build'
gcc -Wl,--build-id=none -nostdlib -static -Wl,-T,../../lib/user/user.lds tests/userprog/multi-recurse.o tests/lib.o lib/user/entry.o libc.a -o tests/userprog/multi-recurse
/usr/bin/ld: tests/lib.o:/home/pairman/Documents/PintOS/userprog/build/../../tests/lib.c:8: multiple definition of `test_name'; tests/userprog/multi-recurse.o:/home/pairman/Documents/PintOS/userprog/build/../../tests/userprog/multi-recurse.c:10: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../Makefile.userprog:39: tests/userprog/multi-recurse] 
Error 1 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pairman/Documents/PintOS/userprog/build'
make: *** [../Makefile.kernel:10: all] Error 2
```

Part of the related code:

tests/lib.c:

```
#include "tests/lib.h"
#include <random.h>
...
#include <syscall.h>

const char *test_name;

...
```

tests/lib.c:

```
#ifndef TESTS_LIB_H
#define TESTS_LIB_H

#include <debug.h>
...
#include <syscall.h>

extern const char *test_name;

...

#endif /* test/lib.h */
```

tests/userprog/multi-recurse.c:

```
#include <debug.h>
...
#include <syscall.h>
#include "tests/lib.h"

const char *test_name = "multi-recurse";

...
```

My system is Fedora 39 and I'm using the toolchain installed via dnf, not self-compiled. The above code comes from the original repository. I don't know what broke the code on my machine. On my machine, make under `threads` can pass but `userprog` has this issue, while compiling the same code on my campus lab environment has no issue.

I tried to fix declaration in `tests/lib.c` with `#ifndef` and `#define` around it, but this will cause a `no type` error in `tests/userprog/multi-recurse.c`, so what I'm doing is probably wrong.

Is there any way to fix this make error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tests/lib.c`, change `const char *test_name;` to `extern const char *test_name;`.

`const char *test_name;` is a [*tentative definition*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055165/advantage-of-using-extern-in-a-header-file/66056029#66056029), which, in spite of its name, is not a definition itself but may result in the generation of a definition.

Some tools, including versions of GCC and associated tools before GCC version 10, treated multiple definitions resulting from tentative definitions as “common” definitions and coalesced them to a single definition (along with one regular definition if it existed). Your tools are treating definitions from tentative definitions as regular definitions.

You can request the old behavior by adding `-fcommon` to the GCC command(s).

Comment: Thanks for "-fcommon" which fixed my issue. Adding "extern"s won't fix snce many files (test programs) like the "multi-recurse.c" is also compiled and linked anagist "lib.o"("lib.h"). But some of them does not have an "const char *test_name" declared, and will lead to errors.